# Nested if-else not working for custom structure c++

Tags: c++, algorithm, c++11, structure

I have a custom data structure `date` in C++11:

```
struct date {
   int day;
   int month;
   int year;
};
```

I want to compare two `date`s and write function for it:

```
int compare_dates(date a, date b) {
    int result = 0;

    if (a.year < b.year) {
        result = -1;
    } else if (a.year == b.year) {
        if (a.month < b.month) {
            result = -1;
        } else if (a.month == b.month) {
            if (a.day < a.day) {
                result = -1;
            } else if (a.day > a.day) {
                result = 1;
            }
        } else {
          result = 1;
        }
    } else {
        result = 1;
    }

    return result;
}
```

But this function doesn't work correctly. I spent a lot of time to debug it and found some issue in the following part of code:

```
} else if (a.month == b.month) {
    if (a.day < a.day) {
        result = -1;
    } else if (a.day > a.day) {
        result = 1;
    }
} else {
  result = 1;
}
```

There are two screenshots during debugging, [first](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OSfMb.png) on `} else if (a.month == b.month) {` and [second](https://i.stack.imgur.com/B8wYt.png) when I click *next line* in debugger. Such happens for all inputs. Why debbuger did not enter into `if (a.day < a.day) {` or `result = 1;` everytime?

Comment: You may have undefined behaviour elsewhere, which can lead to all kinds of strange things. The error cannot be reproduced by the portions you have shown us. Post a complete piece of code, please. See http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: Thank you @ChristianHackl for the comment, next time I will add code according to *mcve* standard.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try with

```
if (a.day < b.day) {
    result = -1;
} else if (a.day > b.day) {
    result = 1;
}
```

instead of

```
if (a.day < a.day) {
    result = -1;
} else if (a.day > a.day) {
    result = 1;
}
```

The two tests `a.day < a.day` and `a.day > a.day` are ever false, so `result = -1` and `result = 1` are never executed.

I suppose that the compiler optimize the code as follows

```
} else if (a.month == b.month) {
} else {
  result = 1;
}
```

Comment: How exactly can this explain why the program skips a perfectly valid `==` comparison?

Comment: @ChristianHackl - I suppose it's because the code that should be executed when the condition is true is an `if`/`else if` with condition that are ever false

Comment: Is really solve my issue, thank you! But I still confused why debugger does not help me.

Comment: @DmytroRudnitskikh - expanded my answer; hope this respond to your question about the dubbugger.

Comment: @max66 Big thank you again! So stupid mistake, on which I have spent a lot of time.

Comment: @max66 maybe you are interesting to improve this algorithm http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40692789/how-can-i-optimize-compare-function-for-custom-date-structure

Answer (score 1):

It may be that compiler **optimisations** get in your way.

As others have observed, you have two typos inside the block. `a.day < a.day` and `a.day > a.day` are by definition always false. Consequently, nothing can ever happen in the block. There is no observable behaviour. That's probably why the compiler just completely eliminates the entire thing to save speed and/or space.

I don't know which compiler you are using, or which flags you pass it, but if you disable all optimisation, then the debugger should work as you expect. You can also try to put a `std::cout << "...\n";` into the block to enforce some observable behaviour and see if that changes something.

This is also an excellent reason to actually learn how your compiler really works, without all the IDE fluff covering its functionality.

Comment: I use GNU SCC Compiler with `-std=c++11`

Comment: @DmytroRudnitskikh: Then try to add `-O0`.

Answer (score 0):

Line no 25 in screenshot first,

```
if (a.day < a.day)
```

It should be

```
if (a.day < b.day)
```

same mistake is in line 27.